# Submitting value in a Google powered form while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to scrape an online food-ordering website using Mechanize & BS4. The problem I'm facing is that the website has a form that takes location as input powered by Google. When I try filling it using this method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, lxml, mechanize

url = raw_input("Enter URL: ")
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(url)

# 'placeSelectionForm' is the name of the input-field
browser.select_form(name='placeSelectionForm')
control1 = browser.form.controls[0]
control1._value = 'Koramangala'
browser.submit()
soup = bs(browser.response().read(), "lxml")
print soup.prettify()
```

The script works fine for a normal django form that I have made. But the problem here is that the Google powered form is using auto-complete api like this:

[image]

So when I type initials of some location, there are auto-complete suggestions and as soon as I select one option the form auto-submits and I'm taken to a new URL.

Now, the problem with the URL of the new page is that no matter what option I chose in the form, the URL remains the same, and the values that come with the response vary accordingly with the option I chose on previous page.

How can I fill this form (powered by Google maps api) using tools like Mechanize or BS4 or any other such?

Comment: It looks like the website makes use of a lot of Javascript so you may find it difficult to use Mechanize (which can't execute Javascript). You could use the browser's developer tools to see what GET/POST requests are sent and then try to emulate those using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). That could also be difficult so it might be easier to use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite Javascript "heavy" website which you may find difficult to automate with `mechanize`. Here is how you can do make a search, choose one of the suggestions and wait for results to load with [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.swiggy.com/bangalore')

# wait for input to appear and make a search
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pac-input"))).send_keys("Koramangala")

# wait for suggestions to appear
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pac-container div.pac-item")))

# choose the first suggestion
suggestions = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.pac-container div.pac-item")
suggestions[0].click()

# wait for results to load
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "restaurants")))

# TODO: extract results
```

I've added comments to make things clear. Let me know if you want me to expand on any of the parts of the code.

Comment: It works perfectly fine.
How did you decide on the number 10 for the webdriver wait time?

Comment: @vanguard69 it's just a practical value I think. Note that it would wait *up to* 10 seconds checking the expected condition every 500 ms.

Comment: Sounds good, didn't know about EC check of 500ms. BTW Selenium works like a charm.